# express.json() is to recognize the Request Object as a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var helloRouter = require('./routes/hello');

var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var session_opt={
  secret:'keyboard cat',
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialize:false,
  cookie:{maxAge:60*60*1000}
};
app.use(session(session_opt));
app.use('/hello',helloRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**hello.js**

```
var express= require('express');
   var router = express.Router();

   router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    var msg = 'write something';
    if(req.session.message != undefined){
        msg = "Last Message"+req.session.message;
    }
    var data={
        title:'Hello',
        content:msg
    };
    res.render('hello',data);
});

router.post('/post',(req,res,next)=>{

    console.log(req.body);


    var msg = req.body['message'];
    req.session.message=msg;
    var data={
        title:'Hello!',
        content:"Last Message"+req.session.message
    };
    res.render('hello',data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**hello.ejs**

```
<form action="/hello/post" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="message">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I understand what express.json() will do from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51844327/10145453)  (No.5 a)
Then I debug my above coding using console.log(req.body) in hello.js

when I submitted the form, this was displayed

**Using express.json()**

```
[Object: null prototype] { message: 'ABC' }
```

**Not using express.json()  (I deleted it from app.js)**

```
[Object: null prototype] { message: 'ABC' }
```

So There is nothing different.what is the purpose for using express.json(). 
even I don't know my understanding of express.json() is correct or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't submitting JSON, so it does nothing.

Your `req.body` comes from `express.urlencoded()`, which parses the body from the HTML form.

Comment: I understand. So, In this case, how can I check JSON one?

Comment: I appreciate you. I understood I was not sending JSON request after I used postman(chrome extension [Tabbed Postman - REST Client]).