# Extracting of HTTP Post in Node Express doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, request

I am trying to send an HTTP POST request from my HTML frontend to a Node.js Express backend. The frontend uses XMLHttpRequest, but when I send the request, the server only receives an empty object. I would appreciate some help in debugging this issue.

Node.js Backend:

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/save_options', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Frontend

```
let DATA_FRONTEND_OPTIONS = {
  "test":"1"
}

function save_options_to_database() {
  var do_it_async = true;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onload = function () {
    var status = request.status;
    var data = request.responseText;
  }

  request.open("POST", "/save_options", do_it_async);

  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  //request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

  request.send(JSON.stringify(DATA_FRONTEND_OPTIONS));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add
`app.use(express.urlencoded());`
to your express configuration.

Here is great explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51844327/8522881

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` for POST request.

**Example:**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Because in POST request the data which is sending is in form of some type of data object and you have to tell the server to accept or store that type of data (object), which is enclosed in the body of your POST request.

Above the same solution applied for PUT requests also.

Comment: Thanks, I got It working, but didnt use app.use(express.urlencoded()). Do I really need both?

Comment: As per data you sending, you have to use.
`express.json()` is recognise the incoming request object as a **JSON Object**.
`express.urlencoded()` is  recognise the incoming request object as **strings or arrays**.